# React -Redux: How to pass the text box value as an argument to dispatch method while dispatching the action on submit event

Tags: react-redux

please advise how to pass the input value to the dispatch method.I want to pass the policy number to the action method in index.js which is in action folder.The retrievepolicy method need to get the policy number as an argument

On submit event,the retrievepolicy method will be dispatched

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { sayHello } from '../actions'
import { retrievePolicy } from '../actions'

class Button extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  policyNumber: ""
}
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
render() {
const { saySomething, retrievePolicy, whatsUp } = this.props;

return (
<div class="container">
<div class="text-white bg-dark" >
<button class="btn btn-info" onClick={saySomething}>PRESS TO DISPATCH 
 FIRST ACTION</button>
 <h2>{whatsUp}</h2>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><label for="exampleInputEmail" class="label">Policy Number</label> 
 </td>
  <td><input type="textbox" class="textarea" id="policyNumberid" 
  name="policyNumberid"
  value={this.state.policyNumber} onChange={this.handleChange}
  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Data Location</td>
  <select class="form-control" id="timezone" name="timezone" 
   selected="selected"  >
   <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
   <option value="Test">\\w</option>
   <option value="Stage">\\ws</option>
   </select>
   </tr>
   <tr><button class="btn btn-info" onClick={retrievePolicy} >Retrieve 
    Policy Information</button></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
    }
    handleChange(typedText) {
    alert('hi')
    this.setState({ policyNumber: typedText.target.value }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.policyNumber);
    });
    }
    };
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    whatsUp: state.policy,
    stateObject: state
    })
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
    {
    saySomething: () => { dispatch(sayHello()) },
    retrievePolicy: (policyNumber) => { 
    dispatch(retrievePolicy(policyNumber)) }
    }
    )
    Button = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Button)
    export default Button
```